# How to pass an object into a partial?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Isn't this how you pass an object to a partial:

```
<% @answers.each do |answer| %>
  ...
  <%= render 'form_for_answer_comment', :answer => answer %> ?
<% end %>
```

My partial looks like:

```
<%= form_for([@question, @answer, @comment]) do |f| %>
```

I get the following error:

Routing Error

```
No route matches {:action=>"create", :controller=>"questions/answers/comments", :format=>nil, :question_id=>#<Question id: 3, user_id: 1, title: "test", description: "asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf\r\n\r\n\tasdfasd", created_at: "2011-09-10 01:33:38", updated_at: "2011-09-10 01:33:38">, :answer_id=>#<Answer id: nil, user_id: nil, question_id: nil, description: nil, selected: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>}
```

However, it works with:

```
<%= form_for([@question, Answer.first, @comment]) do |f| %>
```

I suspect the problem is that its not passing the @answer object to the partial correctly. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Always pass to the partials only local variables, not the instance variables, like you have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
<%= render :partial => 'form_for_answer_comment', :locals => { :answer => answer } %>
```

Then, in your partial, call it without `@`, e.g:

```
<%= form_for([@question, answer, @comment]) do |f| %>
```

Comment: I get undefined local variable or method `answer'

Comment: possibly the locals only get passed when you use render partial: 'form_for_anser_comment', locals: {answer: answer). the key bit being the word partial after render

Comment: @rm-rf was right, I was missing the `:partial => .. ` keyword, my bad - fixed. Also, note that his comment has ruby 1.9.x syntax (won't work with 1.8.7, if that's what you're using).

Comment: This works: render 'form_for_answer_comment', { :answer => answer }. If you pass a string as the first args, the second arg has to be the locals hash